# How to resume android app without losing activities stack (or the app state) with deep linking?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

I have this `<intent-filter>` that every time certain link is pressed it opens my app but the problem is it opens a **new** instance of my app. **Is there anyway to trigger onResume() and just resume my app without losing its state or the activities stack?**

This is the intent filter:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="example.com" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

## Update

Thanks to user David Wasser answer below I found answer:

So I created EntryActivity which is launched on top of gmail/inbox app:

```
public class EntryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.entry_activity);

        Uri uriParams = getIntent().getData();

        Log.e("EntryActivity", uriParams.getHost() );
        Log.e("EntryActivity", uriParams.getQueryParameter("uid") + " " + uriParams.getQueryParameter("type") + " " + uriParams.getQueryParameter("token") );


        Intent startCategory = new Intent(this, GotEmailActivity.class);
        startCategory.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startCategory);
        this.finish();
    }

}
```

Then when my app is opened at GotEmailActivity I send email to user with link to open app and GotEmailActivity  has attribute `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in AndroidManifest so only 1 instance of it is opened:

```
    <!-- 
        Important: notice android:launchMode="singleTop"
        which seeks if an instance of this activity is already opened and
        resumes already opened instance, if not it opens new instance.
     -->
    <activity
        android:name=".presenters.register.email.GotEmailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_got_email"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
```

Now what is happening is that EntryActivity is opened ontop of Gmail app but it closes inmediatle but first launches GotEmailActivity which is already opened so attribute launchMode Singletop prevents a new instance of such activity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should create another `Activity` that you use as an entry point to your application when responding to that `<intent-filter>`. Something like this:

What you need is just a simple Activity that does nothing. Here is an example:

```
public class EntryActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Check to see if this Activity is the root activity
        if (isTaskRoot()) {
            // This Activity is the only Activity, so
            //  the app wasn't running. So start the app from the
            //  beginning (redirect to MainActivity)
            Intent mainIntent = getIntent(); // Copy the Intent used to launch me
            // Launch the real root Activity (launch Intent)
            mainIntent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
            // I'm done now, so finish()
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            finish();
        } else {
            // App was already running, so just finish, which will drop the user
            //  in to the activity that was at the top of the task stack
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Put your `<intent-filter>` on this activity, instead of your "launcher" Activity. Make sure that in the manifest the task affinity of this activity is the same as the task affinity of the other activities in your application (by default it is, if you haven't explicitly set **android:taskAffinity**).

When the `<intent-filter>` gets triggered, if your application is running, then the `EntryActivity` will be started **on top** of the topmost activity in your application's task and that task will be brought to the foreground. When the `EntryActivity` finishes, it will simply return the user to the topmost activity in your application (ie: wherever the user left it when it went into the background).

If your app was **not running**, the `EntryActivity` recognizes this and starts your app from the beginning, passing it the `Intent` containing the ACTION and DATA that triggered the `<intent-filter>`.

Should work.

Comment: Hi David thanks for answer I was trying to understand what taskAffinity does but it is not very clear. What we basically want is to re-open previously opened app from a link that could be in say chrome, oepera, dolphin or default any other android browser. But what deep link  is doing is opening a new session or instance of my same app, how can we just re launch app from the state it was, without losing activitties stack and the state of the app when user clicks such link in the browser?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you give an example of a link that is used to do this?

Comment: If you are in control of the links, then you can craft a "launch URL" for your app that would simulate the user tapping your app icon on the HOME screen. This would either start your app (if it wasn't already running) or bring the existing task hosting your app to the foreground. Is that what you want? Can you craft the link? This won't work using `<intent-filter>`

Comment: Yes this is a link: http://example.myapp.delivery/auth/login?type=pwdless&token=546aa9df79a7559ba75d00c5795fad0eed30f56990901dad7a651db60b7b6b485172e42ad2e7dfe5303b54c5629d160b&uid=EA1FBE, What happens is that user must be able to re open app once this link is clicked which is provided from the browser.

Comment: YESS!! that is exactly what I want to **re open** app to the foreground and take some parameters from link how to do this?

Comment: If you need to take parameters from the link then you can't use a "launch URL". A launch URL would only bring the task to the foreground, but wouldn't give you access to any of the data in the URL. The solution I have given you already will do what you want

Comment: ok thanks I'll try with the taskAffinity to see if it works will come back after to update my progress many thanks!

Comment: so I put both the EntryActivity and the Activity I need to resume with the same `android:taskAffinity="com.example.registry"` in the AndroidManifest, but when user clicks link on gmail/inbox app (we send the link to the user in its mail), what is happening is that the EntryActivity is being opened on top of gmail/inbox app (thus leaving 2 instances of my app running the previous one and a new one on top of gmail app), is there any way to force it to open ONLY on top of my app?

Comment: The problem here is that you need to force **other** applications to start your `Activity` using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Unfortunately, this isn't possible. What you could try is to set `taskAffinity=""` (this means no task Affinity) on `EntryActivity. This means that it will launch into the Gmail task. Then, instead of using the `isTaskRoot()` code in my answer, just have `EntryActivity` **always** call `startActivity()` with `MainActivity` and then call `finish()`. Make sure to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on that `Intent` before you call `startActivity()`.

Comment: That should decouple your app from Gmail. There may be other issues with this solution. See how far you get.

Comment: thanks again for guidace. But, I imagine that alternative won't save the navigation stack and state of my previously opened app

Comment: Any existing task containing your app will just be brought to the foreground. All activities and state will still be there. The flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` doesn't tell Android to throw away any existing task hosting your app and create a new one. It tells Android that you don't want the Activity launched into the Gmail task!

Comment: oh okay Ill try with this.

Comment: What you are trying to do basically goes against the standard Android approach. This is why it may be a bit complicated to get a solution that will work. But it should be possible. It just isn't the way Android is designed to work.

Comment: Yeah this is a rare use case I'm aware of that but my employer wants some new type of login into the app so we are trying this approach thanks for your help and guidance!

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: @Anu Solution for what? This answer provides a solution to OP's question. Open a new question if this doesn't solve your problem.